# Promise.all is not waiting for all promises to get resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise

Promise.all is not waiting for all promises to get resolved.In Below code I am trying to replicate a scenarios where depending on some service (two services) response I would be setting the array and then when all service call is done, process.all will give the captrued value. However this does not work.

```
let errorPromises = [];
    setTimeout(() => {
      errorPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(1000)));
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      errorPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(3000)));
    }, 1000);

    let promise = Promise.all(errorPromises);
    promise.then(data => {
      console.log("All done", data);
    });
```

it should print "All done [1000,3000]" but it prints "All done []"

Please help.

Comment: At the time that you call `Promise.all`, the promises haven't been added to the array yet - you're basically just calling `Promise.all([])`, which resolves instantly.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you are creating promises after the timeout. You need to wrap the timeout in Promise instead

```
let errorPromises = [];

errorPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(1000), 2000);
}));

// or a one-liner
// errorPromises.push(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(1000), 2000)));

/// repeat with all others...

let promise = Promise.all(errorPromises);
promise.then(data => {
  console.log("All done", data);
});
```

Comment: Hi @smnbbrv, this solution works in above case but when I added this soultion to the origianl issue it does not work and gives same issue.

Comment: this.productService.getPromotionalData().subscribe(
      (d: PromotionalData[]) => {
        this.slides = d;

        errorPromises.push(
          new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(3000), 0))
        );
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log("An error occurred:", err.error.message);
        }
    );

Comment: this happens because in the example you gave first the errors are collected synchronously; the example you gave later uses observable. If you already have `rxjs` you might want to use rxjs methods instead, e.g. [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator, but this is definitely going to be a subject of another question

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you create the promise, before your error promises are in the array. It will take 1 and 2 seconds for the promises to be pushed in the array with timeout, so you get what you want if you wait that the array contains something, for example if you set timeout for the promise too, which should happen AFTER the promises are pushed in to the array.

```
let errorPromises = [];
    setTimeout(() => {
      errorPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(1000)));
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      errorPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(3000)));
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
        let promise = Promise.all(errorPromises);
        promise.then(data => {
          console.log("All done", data);
        });
    }, 3000);
```

So basically you trigger the console log instantly, and then your array is still empty because of the timeout.

```
 let errorPromises = [];
 errorPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(1000)));
 errorPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(3000)));

 let promise = Promise.all(errorPromises);
 promise.then(data => {
  console.log("All done", data);
 });
```